# reference of object of "graduate from"

Tags: collocations

Can the object of "graduate from" be "the department of history," for example?
Does it have to be "university" or "college"?

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is the university which awards your degree, you would normally use "graduate" with the university or college, not the department. While "I graduated from the department of history is understandable, you can instead say

> I graduated with a degree in history.